# tablesorter onRenderHeader option with Scroller Not working

Tags: jquery, plugins, tablesorter

I am using  tablesorter plugin with scroller widget. I am trying to use onRenderHeader option to bind a click event to a checkbox which is placed in the header and its not working. I removed the scroller widget and it works as expected. 
Is there any way to make onRenderHeader option work with scroller.

This is how I am applying the tablesorter plugin to my html table:

```
$('#tableone').tablesorter ({
    theme : 'blue',
    widthFixed : false,
    initWidgets : true,
    showProcessing : true,
    dateFormat : "mmddyyyy",
    headerTemplate : '<input class="image" type="image" src="IMG/minus.jpg" width="15px"><span class="text">{content}{icon}</span>',

    // customize header HTML
    onRenderHeader : function (index) {
        // the span wrapper is added by default
        $(this).find('.image').on('click', function () {
            $(this)[0].attr("src", "IMG/plus.jpg");
        });
    },
    widgets : ['scroller', 'filter', 'columnSelector', 'columns']
}).tablesorterPager({
    container : $(".pager"),
    output : '{startRow} to {endRow} of {totalRows} records',
    size : 25
});
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Any idea if tablesorter onRenderHeader option works with scroller widget ?

Comment: I got this worked , unbind the events on sorting images inside document.ready(), then call the tablesorter on your html table , then bind your new event to the newly added element in the header.Note : I did not use onRenderHeader Option , rewrote the code as <th><div><image></image><textarea></textarea></div><SORTICONS OF TABLESORTER></th>